# How to schedule a task for UPA Photo update

Tags: user-profile-service, scheduled-tasks

I setup a task schedule to run ps1 to update photo store.  I notice that photos aren't being updated. But when I to run the update-spprofilephotostore manually then photos are updated?

http://www.sysadminsblog.com/microsoft/scheduling-the-update-spprofilephotostore-command/

```
$mysitesUrl = "http://mysite.company.org"
$mySitesHost = Get-SPSite –Identity $mySitesUrl
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore –MySiteHostLocation $mySitesHost –CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos $true
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brandonclaps.com/?p=37

I had to create a new schedule task instead of importing an existing one. I followed the above link and it worked. Also make sure Add-snapin sharepoint is in the sp1 file.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation http://mysitehostlocation/MySite/
```

Save the file as a .ps1 file on your SharePoint 2010 server – C:\Scripts\UpdateSPPhotos.ps1

Create a daily scheduled task on the SharePoint 2010 server that runs at the SharePoint Farm Administrator account.

Configure the action as follows

Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Arguments: -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File "C:\Scripts\UpdateSPPhotos.ps1"